# Way to detect if a group deployment changed anything?

Tags: azure, azure-cli

When creating a script around `az group deployment create`, I want to detect if any resource was actually modified. Ideally, I would want to do this for `az group deployment validate`, as I understand it to be basically a dry run of create.

I was comparing the output but I can’t seem to find a difference if the ressource previously existed (and was identical) or if it differed or didn’t exist.

I could obviously use the `show` command and compare the JSON myself, but that would require me to understand what to compare, which doesn’t look trivial.

Ideas?

Comment: can you explain more on  your question. Do you want to check if the resource group exist ?

Comment: I want to see if running ”az group deployment create” will change anything or if everything is up to date. Ideally also what it changed, but at least the resource groups that will change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And Microsoft finally implemented the feature I was looking for

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-deploy-what-if?tabs=azure-powershell#install-azure-cli-module

It is still in preview as of this writing, but from the documentation it looks like exactly what I was asking for.

Comment: Nice. `validate` only makes a syntax validation of the template. This `what-if` seems more like dry-run functionality.